# Hide content on mobile, CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

I'm modifying my WordPress theme so I can change the header image on mobile. I've come pretty close. I removed the header image from the theme's customization and installed a custom header plugin.

I added this to my stylesheet:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
   #headerimagemobile { display:none; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
   #headerimagenotmobile { display:none; }
}
```

And this to my custom header:

```
<div id="headerimagemobile" align="center">
<img src="http://www.zordonsboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Zordons-Boy-Site-Header-PNG-Retina-1.png" alt="Zordon's Boy Header">
</div>

<div id="headerimagenotmobile" align="center">
<img src="http://www.zordonsboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Zordons-Boy-Site-Header-PNG-Retina.png" alt="Zordon's Boy Header" style="width:958px">
</div>
```

Here's the site: http://www.zordonsboy.com

It looks like it works in a desktop browser. One image is there when maximized, then it switched as you shrink the window. But on mobile, I get both images. I got 800px from my theme, it's the cutoff it uses to be responsive on mobile.

Any clue what else I have to do?

EDIT: I have a down vote which apparently means I gave no research effort. I've been researching this for the last four hours and this is where I've ended up. I've found javascript and jquery results but I can't figure out how to incorporate them into the html custom header.

Comment: hi, I just checked your site in both desktop(resizing the window also) as well as on mobile(Chrome browser for mobile). When on smaller screen, it's only showing a single logo! I believe you have not refreshed the browser cache and the old css file might be getting pulled from the cache instead of your updated version! Try clearing the browser cache of your mobile.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the css stored in the cache.

Comment: Glad to hear that it's sorted out. :) Yeah, browsers have a cache mechanism which helps in speeding up the loading of website on the successive calls. I will post it as an answer so that you could mark it as answer.

Comment: Bad form to have min/max at the same value. One should be 799 and the other 800 or 801 and 800.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked your site in both desktop(resizing the window also) as well as on mobile(Chrome browser for mobile). When on smaller screen, it's only showing a single logo! I believe you have not refreshed the browser cache and the old css file might be getting pulled from the cache instead of your updated version! Try clearing the browser cache of your mobile.

Because almost all of the browsers keeps a cache mechanism to speed up the loading of the website next time. Most of the time, the images, the CSS files, the Javascript files, etc would be stored in the cache. So when you make changes, always try to do hard refresh(Ctrl+F5 if you are on desktop) on the webpage or try to clear the browser cache, so that a fresh copy of the site contents is loaded.